# Proxying HTTPS using Node.js (without SSL certificate)

Tags: node.js, https, proxy

I'm trying to setup a local server to proxy some of the requests to a remote https server, where some files are served locally.

It can be done using apache mod_ssl, mod_proxy, without asking me a certificate for my local server. But in node.js's "http-proxy", it requires a certificate.

So, is there a way to have the node https-proxy running without a certificate? or where my thoughts went wrong? And how about HTTP to HTTPS proxy without certificate?